# Print text from input area fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few input fields and some static text. I need that to be printed but can not get it to work. Can you please help me?

```
<div class="modal-body" id="printable-consent">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="patient-surname-consent">Patient’s surname/family name : </label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" id="patient-surname-consent" onkeyup="printDiv()" name="patient-surname-consent" value="" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="patient-firstname-consent">First name: </label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" id="patient-firstname-consent"  onkeyup="printDiv()" name="patient-firstname-consent" value="" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I want to type text in the modal box and that to be print (sent to printer). Can you help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: When you say 'print', do you mean send to a printer and print an actual A4 page? Because your `printDiv()` function is called **`onkeyup`**, which would mean every letter you type would trigger the function; that seems like it would waste a lot of paper... Also, have you written any `printDiv()` function so far? If so, please include in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If not, [**try to write it**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Comment: Please, update your question  adding your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using JavaScript and the "value" property of the element.

For example,

```
var myPatientFirstName = document.querySelector("#patient-firstname-consent").value;

console.log(myPatientFirstName);
```

Comment: We don't typically reward poor questions with answers as it just encourages more poor questions.